# Can a pre-validated transaction permanently fail? If so, how to detect this?

Tags: transactions, finality

When a transaction is accepted by a node and pre-validated is it possible that the transaction will ultimately fail to reach finality? How can the client that pushed the transaction detect this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the eosio::history_api_plugin then you can query all transactions relevant to the accounts specified in the config file. You can then learn if and when the transaction was included and whether it is irreversible.